# Filling out form fields in Opera where the wand doesn't cover

Tags: opera, userscripts

Is there a function in Opera that allows me to fill in form fields with repeated information or data that isn't covered by the Magic Wand? Or a way to have Opera's Wand be able to store information for other fields?

Or maybe there's a userscript that could do this instead?

To give you one example: when logging into any of the Stack Exchange sites, I need to manually enter (or enter from a note) the URL of the OpenID provider. I would like to automate this in particular plus several other sites where a similar situation exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple UserScript:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            OpenID fill out for StackExchange sites
// @include         http://superuser.com/users/login*
// @include         http://stackoverflow.com/users/login*
// @include         http://serverfault.com/users/login*
// @include         http://*.stackexchange.com/users/login*
// ==/UserScript==
(function ()
{
    window.addEventListener('load', function()
    {
        document.getElementById('openid_identifier').value = "https://your.url/for/openid";
        document.getElementById('show-more-options').style = '';
    }, false);
})();
```

Comment: I edited your answer to contain my improved version. It limits the scope (`@include`) and makes the invisible edit field and the button visible (`.style=''`). Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

Opera already has this covered for form entry fields you use often and repeatedly in the Forms data manager found in the Preferences panel.

1. Bring it up with either <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>
2. Click on the *Forms* tab.
3. Fill it in as required.
4. Click **OK**

Next time you're on a site with a text input field, you can just tap on the down arrow or right-click for the context menu and select from the **Insert Personal** options.

[image: form fields context menu]

Comment: I am aware of this particular feature, but it's still cumbersome when you know you have to fill it in every single time. Also right now I know how to do it on other sites, if I need it. Thanks for the effort, though (and +1 for that).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with both the other answers, but thought for completeness' sake I'd point out that there's a [useful autocomplete extension](https://addons.opera.com/en/addons/extensions/details/autocomplete/) that's a bit more generic than having a userscript for each similar case, and a bit more flexible than the "Insert Personal" fields provided out of the box.

Comment: And indeed, thank you for that :) +1